# How to include existing fields in mongodb aggregation $project operation

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample collection `articles` which contains the following data:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : "post 1",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 5
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "post 2",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 9
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "post 3",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 8
}
```

I would like to use the aggregation framework to find the min and max value for page views for a given author, and in the process display the _id of the article with the min/max value. This is my expected output:

```
{ _id    : "Bob", 
   value : { min : { page_views : 5 , _id : "post 1" } , 
             max : { page_views , 9 , _id : "post 3" } } }
```

I've tried implementing this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {
        "$group":  {
            "_id": "$author",
            "min_page_views": {
                "$min": "$page_views"
            },
            "max_page_views": {
                "$max": "$page_views"
            }
        }            
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "min": {
                "page_views": "$min_page_views",
                "_id": "$_id"                
            },
            "max": {
                "page_views": "$max_page_views",
                "_id": "$_id"                
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "Bob",
            "min" : {
                "page_views" : 5,
                "_id" : "Bob"
            },
            "max" : {
                "page_views" : 9,
                "_id" : "Bob"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I cannot seem to get the other field `max._id` or `min._id` which gives the original document id before projection. How do I change my aggregation pipeline so that I can include this field as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could modify your `aggregate` pipeline as below:

- Include a [**$sort**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) stage before your [**$group**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
  stage operator to get the records in ascending order.
- Then get the [**$first**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [**$last**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) records per group
  which would hold the `lowest` and `highest` viewed pages respectively, for each author.

[**$$ROOT**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT)  is a system variable, which is used to refer to the top level element, of the currently being processed document.

Modified code:

```
db.articles.aggregate([
{$sort:{"page_views":1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$author",
         "max":{$last:"$$ROOT"},
         "min":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
{$project:{"max.page_views":1,
           "max._id":1,
           "min.page_views":1,
           "min._id":1}}
])
```

sample o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : "Bob",
        "max" : {
                "_id" : "post 2",
                "page_views" : 9
        },
        "min" : {
                "_id" : "post 1",
                "page_views" : 5
        }
}
```